# How to show my publisher name in click once installation

Tags: wpf, windows-8, clickonce

I published a WPF application from VS properties window. When I try to run the setup.exe file generated Windows smart screen protection is popping up and when I click more the publisher is showing as unknown publisher (even though I signed using a valid code signing certificate issued by verisign). Do I need to do anything else other than signing my application to be able to show my publisher name. I tired to install on another pc running WIndows 7 and its working fine there.